# Why is there a red output while nothing is wrong in Linux?

Tags: linux

I have seen it over and over again. I wonder why an output is red while there is not an error in Linux, while downloading packages for example.

Vagrant

[image]

Docker

[image]

Comment: To make it stand out as it is deemed important by the team that prepares the packages. Red color doesn't have to imply an error, the actual text does.

Answer (score 2):

Docker is printing anything that comes from the stderr of a `RUN` command in red. I agree that standard error doesn't mean that this text is about an error in fact; just that it should not be piped to other commands, being intended for diagnostics or human consumption.

If you try building this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine
RUN echo "Hello world stdout"
RUN echo "Hello world stderr" 1>&2
```

you will see only `Hello world stderr` printed in red.

Comment: so is there a way to overcome it ? it is really ugly

Comment: I haven't seen this in recent Docker versions that use BuildKit as they are better at dealing with lengthy output from Dockerfiles.

Comment: @GorovDude You can redirect stderr back to stdout, so that docker will not see anything in stderr, and this way it will not be colored red.